# I want to get data from javascript object

Tags: reactjs

image link here:

[image]

I want to get 'weather -0 - icon.
How can I get this?
thank you

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric`)
    .then(response => {
      
      setCurrentWeather(response.data);
      console.log(response);
    })
  }, [])

.............

  <div>temperature {currentWeather.main?.temp} Celcius</div>
  <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${currentWeather?.weather?.icon}@2x.png`} alt=""></img>
  <div>wind {currentWeather.wind?.speed} m/s</div>
```

Comment: Let's see what you've tried

Comment: I try this code. but image code error.

Comment: I got error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Comment: Can you just post the object not img?

Comment: and without ? I got error. I have to write ?.

Comment: api docs here :  https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions#Icon-list

Comment: Why do you have to make the people want to help you, go through all the img and link stuff? Shouldn't be easier just post the `object`?

Comment: problem here:    https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/getting_data_from_server#exercises-2-11-2-14

Comment: sorry, I try this problem many hours. . error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: I try this code. <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${currentWeather?.weather[0]?.icon}@2x.png`} alt=""></img>. and I got error

Comment: I will try to post the object. thank you Enfield li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getWeatherIcon(currentWeather){
  const weather = currentWeather.weather;
  if(isArray(weather)){
    return weather[0]?.icon ?? '';
  }
  return '';
}
```

If you'll get undefined or with this function - empty string,
it's because the response didn't had this field.

Answer (score 0):

please provide more information about the code.

this is an array with a length of 0. if you want only the first item you could call the array like this: `weather[0].icon` but you may need to select all icons from all items from an array. so you might need to use `for loop` or `map` method